# Oracle Total Recall and Views

Tags: oracle

I'm creating a fairly in-depth temporal database prototype in which we are using Oracle's Total Recall to manage transaction times.

My test dataset has about 150k current rows along with 170k retired rows loaded into a FLASHBACK ARCHIVE enabled table. The augmented SQL queries (like the first one below) are executing correctly providing the appropriate data results.

```
select * 
from CUT_BLOCK_COMBO AS OF TIMESTAMP FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP('2007-08-28 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'UTC')
WHERE CB_SKEY = 4141;
```

This select statement returns the following data:

```
    CB_SKEY    HVA_SKEY FOREST_FILE_ID CUTTING_PERMIT_ID TIMBER_MARK CUT_BLOCK_ID 
----------- ----------- -------------- ----------------- ----------- ------------ 
       4141       53094 A80053                           80053       29025
```

However once I wrap the table up into a view, I can no longer query the data with the 'AS OF TIMESTAMP' clause.

```
create or replace view CUT_BLOCK_COMBO_VW as select * from CUT_BLOCK_COMBO;
```

```
select * 
from CUT_BLOCK_COMBO_VW AS OF TIMESTAMP FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP('2007-08-28 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'UTC')
WHERE CB_SKEY = 4141;
```

The select statement from the view returns the following error: *ORA-01466: unable to read data - table definition has changed*

Any ideas what I missed when creating the view definition? I couldn't find anything in the docs ([Oracle Total Recall 11G R2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25518/adfns_flashback.htm))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it work as an in-line view?

I would suspect that the view would have to have existed as-of the timestamp. Possibly the code is looking for the create date or last DDL time on the object against which you are using AS OF.

Just a theory, but you could test it pretty easily I think, and possibly prove the theory by tracing the execution.

If that's the case then I can't think of a safe workaround I'm afraid.

Comment: I cross posted the questions to Ask Tom - he explained a few more of the details about how the 'AS OF' clause gets applied to the objects.  [Ask Tom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:2048074500346953246)

Comment: I suppose one critical aspect is that the view definition could actually have been modified from something completely different at some point. I suspect that it's actually the last_ddl_time that flashback looks for.